# Asp.net button visibility using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button

I am using a simple Asp.Net button and trying to hide it on page load event and I want to show it back after doing some client side script.

I have tried out by this way `document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID %>').style.visibility = "visible";`  and its not showing me up.

So how do I enable it back?

Page_Load:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
 Button1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
    $(function () {
        $("#uploader").plupload({
            // General settings
            runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
            url: 'Final.aspx',
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            max_file_count: 25,
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            unique_names: true,

        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        //                    resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [
        { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
        { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
    ],

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: 'js/plupload.flash.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: 'js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });


    // Client side form validation
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');

        // Files in queue upload them first
        if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
            // When all files are uploaded submit form
            uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
                if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                    $('form')[0].submit();
                }
            });

            uploader.start();
        }
        else
            alert('You must at least upload one file.');

        return false;
    });
    var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');
    uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, res) {
        $('#showfilelist').append("<div id=" + file.id + " class='thumb'><a href='uploads/" + document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value + "/" + file.name + "' target='_blank' rel='gallery'><img src='uploads/" + document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value + "/" + file.name + "' width='50' height='50'/></a></div>");
        $('#Maintabs').tabs('enable', 1);
        document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID %>').style.visibility = "visible"; 
    });


});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you set a control's `Visible` property to `false` (on the server side), the control will not be rendered to the client, so there'll be nothing there to change the style of.

If you want to hide it on the server but still render it to the client, set the `visibility` CSS property (via the `Style` property), or assign the element a CSS class that will hide it (via the `CssClass` property).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out in the right way and you have solved my problem!

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for all your suggestions and I have set its visibility as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID %>').style.visibility = "hidden";
}); 
<script>
```

Comment: Thanks Eric and I forgot this little point and struggling for it!

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use the display attribute instead?

```
document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID %>').style.display= '';
document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID %>').style.display= 'none';
```

This way, you're not touching the server attributes, but the client ones. You may have to tweak the above code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If the element is always going to be hidden on page load then I would just set a default class or style that sets `display: none;` and then toggle that with javascript

so in the HTML for you button

```
<asp:button runate="server" id="Button1" CssClass="displayNone"></asp:button>

<script>
  $("#Button1").removeClass(displayNone");
</script>

<style>
  .displayNone { display: none; }
</style>
```